# How can I delete multiple globally assigned lists with a for loop?

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7, for-loop, global-variables

If I have these lists (which are much larger in reality)

```
listSEG00 = ['n', 'n', '4', '3', 'w']
listSEG01 = ['4', '4', '4', '4', '4']
listSEG02 = ['l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l']
listSEG03 = ['5', 'l', '5', '8', '7']
listSEG04 = ['f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f']
listSEG05 = ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
listSEG06 = ['l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l']
listSEG07 = ['l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l']
listSEG08 = ['7', '4', '3', '8', '4']
listSEG09 = ['e', 'x', 'p', '9', 'm']
```

How can I delete many of these at once?

I have this so far:

```
for y in range(0, 10):
    if len(set(eval('listSEG%i' % y))) == 1:
        del eval('listSEG%i' % y)
```

I get an error on the third line.

`SyntaxError: can't delete function call`

So I'm obviously not doing it right.

Comment: Why don't you use list of lists or dictionary of name-list pair?

Comment: Something like `listSEG = [['n', 'n', '4', '3', 'w'], ['4', '4', '4', '4', '4'], ['l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l'], ...]`

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly delete them? You do know `del listSEG00` just unassigns the `listSEG00` variable, right? As soon as you assign a different value to the variable, or as soon as the function `listSEG00` is local to returns if it's a local variable, the reference to the list will disappear, much the same as if you `del`eted it. On the other hand, if other references to the list remain, `del` won't do a thing to the list.

Comment: eval() is a built-in function of python,,and you are trying to del(eval) hence the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commentators are right to suggest you keep these in a dict or not worry about deleting them, however, you do have that ability.

Module level variables can be deleted from the dictionary returned by `globals()`:

```
>>> listSEG00 = ['n', 'n', '4', '3', 'w']
>>> listSEG01 = ['4', '4', '4', '4', '4']
>>> listSEG02 = ['l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l']
>>> listSEG03 = ['5', 'l', '5', '8', '7']
>>> listSEG04 = ['f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f']
>>> listSEG05 = ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
>>> listSEG06 = ['l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l']
>>> listSEG07 = ['l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l']
>>> listSEG08 = ['7', '4', '3', '8', '4']
>>> listSEG09 = ['e', 'x', 'p', '9', 'm']
>>> for i in globals().keys():
...     if i.startswith('list'):
...         del globals()[i]
...
>>> globals()
{'i': '__doc__', '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__
': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>> listSEG00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'listSEG00' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

`del` is a statement. It has special syntax. Essentially, you could use only those expressions that you could put on the left side of an assignment (`=`). And you can't assign to a function call such as `eval()`.

`del name` doesn't remove the value that the `name` refers to. It just unlinks the name. If nothing else refers to the object then it might be removed later by garbage collector. See also [the comment by @user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240861/how-can-i-delete-multiple-lists-with-a-for-loop#comment33775642_22240861). You could empty the lists instead:

```
#XXX don't use it, see alternatives at the end of the answer
for y in range(10): 
    del eval('listSEG%02d' % y)[:] # empty the list
```

If the names are local to the function then they will be automatically removed after you leave the function. Otherwise, you could remove it from appropriate namespace: global (as [shown by @Aaron Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22241137/4279)), builtin, object's `__dict__`:

```
#XXX don't use it, see alternatives at the end of the answer
namespace = globals()
for y in range(10):
    del namespace['listSEG%02d' % y] # remove the name
```

---

If you find yourself creating variable names such as `listSEG00`, `listSEG01`, etc then you should stop and use a list (as [suggested by @falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240861/how-can-i-delete-multiple-lists-with-a-for-loop#comment33775577_22240861)) or a dictionary whatever is more appropriate in your situation.
In that case, you could execute: `del listSEG`, to remove a single name that refers to the nested list or dictionary.